# using hide/show jQuery and innerWidth for specific screen dimensions to hide mobile menu when clicked on anchor link

Tags: jquery, mobile, menu

I have an anchor link in my menu, so when I click on it overlay mobile menu does not dissapear. 
Fot this reason I used hide/show jQuery, what works, but it causes that my desktop screen menu disappears also. I need to add properly innerWidth in my opinion, but I struggle with this.
below the code:

```
$(function() {
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.innerWidth < 769 && ".link5Click".click(function(){
        $('#myNav').hide();
    }));
 else 
    $("#hamburger").click(function(){
        $('#myNav').show();
    })
})
```

});

when I used the following code my hamburger button stopped work

```
var onMobile = window.matchMedia("screen and (max-width: 768px)"); 
if (onMobile.matches) {
    $(".link5Click").click(function() {
    $("#myNav").hide();
});
} else {
    $("#hamburger").click(function() {
    $('#myNav').show();
});
}
```

Comment: all is fine , i discovered what was wrong  all works

Answer (score 0):

By the way if you want to just hide and show some element or menu you can achieve this using CSS media queries and use display:block or display:none based on screen sizes.

Also if you want different element work differently based on screen size, lets say on mobile by clicking you want to hide menu and on desktop on clicking you want to display menu.You can assign a CSS class based on media query and can apply that class through vanilla js or jQuery, because of media query the class will act differently based on screen size.

Hope you get the idea.

Comment: YES You are right about hide/show elelments it works like that, BUT I am talking about JS/jQuery  function, and mobile menu which is in JS I have to manipulate with JS/jQuery it is not about media query .  I have a mobile menu with overlay background, I use anchor link to contact section what is on the same page, so page does not reload and the menu overlay after clicking on the menu link does not dissapear.

Comment: Can you share your code snippet for better understanding?